# В spring-boot приложение запускается чужая форма

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

как только подключаю в build.grade зависимость:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

сразу выводится форма авторизации какая-то непонятная, которой у меня даже в шаблонах нет.

вот все настройки:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Не чужая, а сгенерирована по умолчанию спрингом

Comment: Вам надо настроить spring security. Для этого можно создать класс наследуемый от WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter и переопределить метод configure(HttpSecurity http). Если Вы хотите поменять только страницу логина, то будет достаточно 
`http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();` Где login это Ваш html файл в директории по умолчанию. Для более гибкой настройки советую почитать гайды по конфигурации spring security.

Comment: чучуть по другой причине было,но ваш комментарий помог,спасибо.Просто файлы с этой конфигурации были в другой папке я вроде подключил их через import к файлу с main ,но он все равно их не видел,щас вот в один pakage сложил их и видит конфигурацию,вот теперь думаю как по разным папкам разложить ,чтобы друг друга файлы видели).